# how to form Mysql Join Query For Single Child multiple parent Relationship?

Tags: mysql, left-join

Say I have tables T1,T2,T3,T4 like this below ERD

[image]

T1 - Dominant Table has 2 child tables (T2,T3), 
T4 has 2 parent tables (T2,T3)

How to form a Left join query for this relationship in mysql

Comment: Which table will you start the `SELECT` from? What are the PK\FK names? Your diagram does not make sense if `T4` is a child of` T2` and `T3`.Please add more information.

Comment: Show CREATE TABLE for all 4 tables, not a drawing... *How to form a Left join query for this relationship in mysql* `t1 left join t2 left join t3 left join t4` or `t1 left join (t2 left join t4 as t41) left join (t3 left join t4 as t42)`, depends on a logic. Parent must be mentioned before the child in any case.

Comment: I have Edited the image martin and akina

Comment: Your scheme seems to be inconsistent. It is possible that the records in t2 and t3 which refer to the same record in t4 refers to different records in t1 (and the same in backward - 2 different records in t4 refers to the same record in t1 via t2 and t3 respectively). I think there is a logical error in database structure. Or there is a scheme error - for example a record in t4 may refer to either t2 or t3, but not both (but the structure does not contain the info what table the record is referred to).

Comment: thanks akina, I just want to know whether this kind of relationship can be left joined example in T4 as (customer/Vendor) table in which one record is pointing its pk to T2(FK2)  and Another record is pointing its pk to T3(Fk2) table in that case is it logically possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible of course. But in such case 1) think - maybe it is more correct to have FK in T2/T3 to T4? 2) Draw 2 copies of T4 table in a scheme (in any case), like `T4 as T4_1` and `T4 as T4_2` (see how MS Access do it in query builder).